# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Tags: python, sqlite, sys

I am trying to get the following MWE to work, however I get the following error:

`words = getWords(sys.argv[1].decode(sys.stdin.encoding)) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

If I remove the decode part as suggested in other questions, it will throw a syntax error for

```
if words:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am uncertain as how to fix this in order to be able to receive the requested results.
Could anyone help me out here?

Thank you and sorry for the question!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import sys
import sqlite3
from collections import namedtuple

conn = sqlite3.connect("wnjpn.db")

Word = namedtuple('Word', 'wordid lang lemma pron pos')

def getWords(lemma):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from word where lemma=?", (lemma,))
  return [Word(*row) for row in cur]

def getWord(wordid):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from word where wordid=?", (wordid,))
  return Word(*cur.fetchone())
 
Sense = namedtuple('Sense', 'synset wordid lang rank lexid freq src')

def getSenses(word):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from sense where wordid=?", (word.wordid,))
  return [Sense(*row) for row in cur]

def getSense(synset, lang='jpn'):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from sense where synset=? and lang=?",
                     (synset,lang))
  row = cur.fetchone()
  return row and Sense(*row) or None

Synset = namedtuple('Synset', 'synset pos name src')

def getSynset(synset):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from synset where synset=?", (synset,))
  return Synset(*cur.fetchone())

SynLink = namedtuple('SynLink', 'synset1 synset2 link src')

def getSynLinks(sense, link):
  cur = conn.execute("select * from synlink where synset1=? and link=?",
                     (sense.synset, link))
  return [SynLink(*row) for row in cur]

def getSynLinksRecursive(senses, link, lang='jpn', _depth=0):
  for sense in senses:
    synLinks = getSynLinks(sense, link)
    if synLinks:
      print( ''.join([' '*2*_depth,
                     getWord(sense.wordid).lemma,
                     ' ',
                     getSynset(sense.synset).name]))
    _senses = []
    for synLink in synLinks:
      sense = getSense(synLink.synset2, lang)
      if sense:
        _senses.append(sense)
        
    getSynLinksRecursive(_senses, link, lang, _depth+1)

def getWordsFromSynset(synset, lang):
  cur = conn.execute("select word.* from sense, word where synset=? and word.lang=? and sense.wordid = word.wordid;", (synset,lang))
  return [Word(*row) for row in cur]

def getWordsFromSenses(sense, lang):
  for s in sense:
    print( getSynset(s.synset).name)
    syns = getWordsFromSynset(s.synset, lang)
    for sy in syns:
      print( '  ' + sy.lemma)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  if len(sys.argv)>=3:
    words = getWords(sys.argv[1].decode(sys.stdin.encoding))
    if words:
      for w in words:
        sense = getSenses(w)
        link = len(sys.argv)>=3 and sys.argv[2] or 'hypo'
        lang = len(sys.argv)==4 and sys.argv[3] or 'jpn'
        if link == 'syns':
          getWordsFromSenses(sense, lang)
        else:
          getSynLinksRecursive(sense, link, lang)
    else:
      print >>sys.stderr, "(nothing found)"
  else:
    print("usage: python jpWordnet.py ピラミッド syns")
```

Comment: This seems to originally be very old, Python 2 era code. (Syntax like `print >>sys.stderr, "(nothing found)"` is a giveaway there.) You're running into differences between Python 2 and Python 3 string handling.

Comment: Removing the `decode` call shouldn't produce the stated error, though. You probably screwed up your parentheses when you did that. (The fact that you didn't report an error for `print >>sys.stderr, "(nothing found)"` is also pretty weird, and suggests you probably weren't running the code you posted, even before removing the `decode` call.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually did run the code and it ran the above stated error (otherwise I would not have found the error). I am not sure what you mean by screw up the parantheses. I used the above MWE as it is.